# Read and write Yaml files with Go

Tags: go, yaml

I have hundreds of yaml files (related to K8s and Helm) with different structures which I use python to edit if needed. I am deciding to learn Go and I wanted to write a new script with go to edit these files but surprisingly I saw that people are creating the yaml structure before reading the yaml file([GO reading YAML file and mapping to slice of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680445/go-reading-yaml-file-and-mapping-to-slice-of-structs) and [Go parse yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682439/go-parse-yaml-file)). What I mean is they create a struct with all the keys in the yaml file with the correct indentation.

I want to know is there a library in Go that you just give it the path to the file and it reads the yaml file dynamically? I want something like python that it reads the file and then you can just access the data similar to a dictionary or data['k1']['k2'] and when you are done with editing just write it back to the file.

### Update

I cannot understand what is wrong with asking about libraries? Isn't this what eventually happens? People suggest different solutions and most of them are using different libraries. On the other hand, I am trying to see where and how to use Go, why my question get off-topic?

Comment: Go is a statically typed language and by its nature not a good fit for this task. It's certainly possible, but all you'll end up seeing in the code are type assertions galore.

Comment: @Peter A YAML document is a composite value containing heterogeneous collections.  While it is certainly not as easy to process as homogeneous structures, I reject the statement that static languages are not a good fit to process it. Remember that an AST also is a very heterogeneous structure and yet most compilers are implemented with statically typed languages. Python code processing YAML usually makes implicit assumptions on the structure, and thus can be translated to Go by making those assumptions explicit via typing. Python code will fail on access, Go code on loading.

Comment: @AVarf Read the `4.` bullet point in the linked *on-topic* help page. The problem is that you're specifically asking for a library. Instead, you should just describe what you actually want to do and why it doesn't work with the solutions you linked. Then someone can suggest a different library, or tell you how to do it with the `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` library used in the linked questions. Currently, your question reads a bit like „I want to use Go but don't want to declare types“ so you should e.g. describe why you can't use `map[string]map[string]int` as target type which would allow `[]` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell the yaml package to unmarshal into an empty interface:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var data interface{}
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("foo: bar"), &data)
    println(reflect.TypeOf(data).String())
}
```

This outputs:

```
map[string]interface {}
```

You'll gets a structure consisting of maps, slices or scalar types depending on the input. Due to Go's static type system, you need to use reflection / casts to access the actual values.

Alternatively, you can unmarshal into a Node:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

func main() {
    var data yaml.Node
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("foo: bar"), &data)
    println(data.Kind)
}
```

This prints `1`, which is a `DocumentNode`. Non-scalar nodes hold their children in the `Content` field; you can walk through the structure by checking each Node's `Kind` and descend for those nodes.